# A word with four numbers

Tags: word, wordplay, lateral-thinking

This is a "mythical" five letter word.

> It has 4 numbers in it.
>
> All the 4 numbers are different.
>
> All the letters in the word are part of those numbers. (no extra letters)

**Hint**

> Think all different numbers, just not Roman Numerals

Comment: Could you clarify if there are 4 "consecutive numbers" or "4 numbers" consecutively. The second line seems redundant if it is the former.

Comment: 5 letters long or 5 unique letters, I wonder?

Comment: 5 letters long like seven

Comment: Is mythical meaning like a true *mythical* word? Similar to **cerberus** or **whisp**?

Comment: Does "just not Roman Numerals" mean that roman numerals are excluded, or that there are other kinds of numbers involved?  If the latter, it should probably read "not just Roman numerals" instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A playful little possibility is a

> pixie which is pi-x-i-e

Comment: You are so good at solving puzzles @Tom

Comment: You should explain the Mythical part of it

Comment: @DEEM - I hope people know these little ones which are part of folklore. This answer needed help obtained from previous posters. I really enjoy your puzzles which are original and neat and am still puzzled by some of Grandpa's sayings.

Answer (score 15):

One option is

> MILD

which contains the numbers

> M (1000), I (1), L (50) and D (500) in Roman numerals.

---

If we allow numbers from other languages, we have the clearly mythical

> Poseidon

which contains the numbers

> **po** (5 in Paraguayan Guarani)
>  **sei** (6 in Italian)
>  **D** (50 in Roman numerals)
>  **on** (10 in Turkish)

Comment: It is not a Mythical word

Comment: And it's not consecutive, I think (Unless my definition of 'consecutive' itself is wrong XD)

Comment: @DEEM, what disqualifies this answer?

Comment: Oh, it's supposed to be consecutive like 5678? I misunderstood that part.

Comment: @jafe. I edited it to make it clearer. My apology. But it is a Mythical word to answer hexomino.

Comment: I like the second guess, as it incorporates four numbers in four completely different languages _and_ fits the mythical criteria. It's just a shame that it's more than five letters.

Comment: @Abion47 The five-letter criterion was added after this.

Answer (score 11):

I believe it's

> DeVIL - deeply rooted in mythology, D = 500, e = euler's number (never said they have to be rational!), V = 5, IL = 49

Comment: Welcome tp PSE @JGibbers. Clever guess and smart way to include "e". My answer is different though.

Comment: Thanks! I think we may end up needing a hint or a clue to the word itself to narrow it down  then (since I think it might be a little broad otherwise?)

Answer (score 3):

I realise it is not a mythical word, but this fits:

> TENON
> The numbers would be TEN, ONE (reversed), NONE (also reversed) and NON (bit suspect)

Comment: a nonet is a group of 9 things

Answer (score 3):

A five letter word which could work, in line with jafe's original answer is

> MIMIC = MI + M + I + C, four different values in Roman numerals.

Other possibilities

> VIVID = VI + V + I + D 
>  LIVID = LI + V + I + D 
>  CIVIL = CI + V + I + L

Comment: Again it needs to be Mythical

Comment: @DEEM - You obviously aren't a fan of pop fantasy.  A Mimic is a living creature that takes the form of a container to draw in prey.  Usually a chest, but could also be a simple box, cabinet, etc.